# Removing event listeners, jquery, memory leak and performance

Tags: jquery, memory, bind, event-listener, unbind

in my web application, the servlet generates a dynamic html page depending on the business rules. i have a container div, which remais always and update its content depending the scenario. suppose, first we add a button and bind a listener on it. Afterwards, we do not need that button and replace the containers content with a textfield for example.

What about the event listeners, do I have to undind them in sake of preventing memory leaks and performance?

Is it a bad design, setting elements with html method? Is it better generating the elements with dom or element creating jquery methods?

current structure:

```
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
```

When we add a button:

```
$('#mainContent').html('<div id=button01></div><script>$('#button01').on('click', function() { //..;
```

Afterwards, suppose we do not need the button and then add a textfield for example.

In the real application, the controls are generated through parsing a json array and 
the main content contains the needed controls.

What about if I do not need for example button01, do I have to call button01.off('click'

Is it better removing the listener and the button itselft manually for example from dom?

Ps. I use jquery 2.x

Answer (score 3):

> What about the event listeners, do I have to undind them in sake of
>   preventing memory leaks and performance?

As long as you only use jQuery methods for manipulating the content (such as `.html()` in your example), then jQuery will take care of cleaning up any items associated with DOM elements that are removed and you should not have any memory leaks.

Where you can cause leaks is if you add event handlers or `.data()` items with jQuery, but then use regular direct DOM manipulation to remove or replace elements.  This can cause small memory leaks associated with the event handlers and can cause memory leaks proportional to the size of whatever you were using with `.data()` on those elements.  While it's better not to have these leaks, the leaks are only for the duration of the current page being on screen so unless you're regularly doing this hundreds of thousands of time during the lifetime of the page or storing gargantuan things in `.data()` references, then the leaks are likely small enough to be immaterial.  You should still be diligent to do things correctly to avoid leaks, but it isn't usually something to worry about.  The only cases I've found where you really have to worry about these kinds of leaks are when you have a really long running page (e.g. perhaps hours of use) with lots of repetitive DOM manipulations such as a single page app or a long running slideshow.

> Is it a bad design, setting elements with html method? Is it better
>   generating the elements with dom or element creating jquery methods?

It is perfectly fine to use the `.html()` method to replace some HTML if that is the easiest and most expedient way to specify what you want done and you want to change that entire tree.

One time when it is not good performance to use `.html()` is when you want to change/replace one element in a large tree of HTML, you should not replace the entire tree with `.html()`, but should rather target just the single element you want to change.  That's because it is more expensive for the browser to throw away a whole bunch of DOM elements and then replace them with all new HTML elements when all you're trying to do is change one element in that section of the hierarchy.

> What about if I do not need for example button01, do I have to call
>   button01.off('click'
>
> Is it better removing the listener and the button itselft manually for
>   example from dom?

If you are removing a DOM element such as a button with jQuery methods (like jQuery's `.remove()` and retaining no references to it, you do not have to manually remove the event handlers.  They will get cleaned up for you by jQuery.